# Set observable value on button click

Tags: knockout.js

On my page I want to track which button the user clicked in an observable:

```
self.action = ko.observable();
```

I can write a function `setAction` and call it with a parameter on each button click, something like this:

```
self.setAction = function (action) {
  self.action(action);
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without having to call each time the `setAction` function?

Comment: [Event delegation in Knockout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/11/revisit-event-delegation-in-knockout-js.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it inline:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: action.bind($data, 'btn-name')">btn-name</button>
```

or pass the actual button object

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: action.bind($data, this)">btn-name</button>
```

Or if your issue is the fact that you have to write this click event each time, you could add a class to each button and add a event listener to set the action.

```
<button type="button" class="btn actionBtn">btn-name</button>

$(".actionBtn").click(function(){
     var btn = $(this);
     viewModel.action(btn);
});
```

Comment: You mean like using jquery attributes? Like the id of button. $(this).attr('id')

Comment: the value of `btn` looks like `div#cancel.tab.actionBtn.tabSelected` is there a way to get only the name?

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: #cancel is the ID. so instead of passing the btn you would do this. viewModel.action(btn.attr('id')); but now your saying name so is the attribute name therefore .attr('name'). update question with jsfiddle demo or boilerplate of button. but i btn.attr('id') will return you 'cancel'

Comment: which implementation did you go with btw? 1st 2nd or 3rd? as im giving u the answer based on 3rd